# Getting error 13 Type mismatch when copying a whole row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting the error 13 type mismatch, while trying to copy a row in VBA.

This is the sub where I'm getting the error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActiveCell.Row
    Dim cel As Range
    If Sh.Name <> "BatchRun" And Sh.Name <> "Document Control" And Sh.Name <> "TC Summary" And Sh.Name <> "Test Cases" And Sh.Name <> "StaticData" And Sh.Name <> "Screenshot" Then
        If Target = Range("A" & i) Then
            Range("A" & i).Cells.ClearContents
            screens
        ElseIf Target = Range("B" & i) Then
            Range("B" & i).Cells.ClearContents
            Environment_list
        ElseIf Target = Range("C" & i) Then
            Range("C" & i).Cells.ClearContents
            Objects
        ElseIf Target = Range("D" & i) Then
            Range("D" & i).Cells.ClearContents
            Keywords_list
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The error is coming from the line `If Target = Range("A" & i) Then`.

Please any help ???

Comment: (a) Is `Target` a single cell?  (b) What is the value in column A? Is it possibly an error value?

Comment: Yes the target is always a single Cell.(Cell from column A or B or C or D). The value is always an item from a list( when clicking on a cell from column A, B, C or D) a list is shown and an item is selected. I think the problem is when clicking on a row not a cell, the error is coming.

Comment: "the target is always a single Cell" - "when clicking on a row not a cell, the error is coming" - Those two statements are contradictory.  If you click on a row, the `Target` is 16384 cells, not just 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with no errors (I had to comment calls to `Sub`s I do not have) whenever the Selection is a single cell.
The error you posted is produced when selecting multiple cells.
Since `Target` is interpreted as the value in `Target`, this cannot be evaluated for multiple cells, thus the error.

You might consider changing the tests, to be more specific, e.g., instead of

```
If Target = Range("A" & i) Then
```

use either

```
If Target.Value = Range("A" & i).Value Then

If Target.Address = Range("A" & i).Address Then
```

or perhaps some alternative.
This may help clarifying the actual test you mean to perform (they could give different results).
If what you need is the first, you should deal with the possible case of multiple selected cells, either by inquiring prior to using `Target.Value` or using `On Error ...`

Note: In the title you mention whole rows, but in a comment you mention you still get the error by selecting single cells, which seems strange.

Comment: FWIW - the OP's last comment (which I think was edited after I first saw it) confirms that they are selecting multiple cells.  So `If Target.Value = Range("A" & i).Value Then` and `If Target.Address = Range("A" & i).Address Then` won't work.  I'm not sure what they **do** want to test.  (Unless, perhaps, they don't want to do **anything** when they select a row - in which case maybe testing the `Address` **is** correct.)

Comment: @YowE3K - When selectin multiple cells, `Target.Address` works fine. As long as you do not use `Target` or `Target.Value`, it should be fine. I tested it.
I am not sure what does he want to accomplish either.

Comment: `Target.Address` will work fine, but will give something like `"$10:$10"` which won't match `"$A$10"` etc so, if they don't want to do anything when selecting a row, it will do what they want.  But if they want to select a row and expect the code to do something, they won't be able to use `Address` as the test.  (P.S. I +1ed your answer, because this is about as good an answer as can be expected if the OP doesn't provide any more info.)

Comment: Thank you all Target.Address works for me Thank you again

Comment: @YowE3K - Of course `"$10:$10"` won't match `"$A$10"`. It is up to the user to handle `Target.Address` (e.g., `"$10:$10"`) appropriately.